# Form action duplicates url

Tags: forms, codeigniter

new to CI and for some reason the form submits to a wrong url.

the result is : `http://localhost/ci/index.php/subjects/localhost/ci/index.php/do_upload`

and can't understand why.
This is the html code :

```
        echo form_open_multipart('do_upload');
    ?>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileupload" 
 style="position:absolute; top:-200px" multiple /> 
    <input type="submit" id="uploadFile" style="position:absolute; top:-200px" />
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Any help?

I've also tried to write `subjects/do_upload` on form open, same thing.

Comment: What do you get when you `echo site_url();`?

Comment: Don't know what it means, i followed the official tutorial... http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Just before `echo form_open_multipart('do_upload');` add `echo site_url(); die();`

Comment: Oh localhost/ci/index.php is the result

Comment: Could it be related to the fact i set this on config.php? $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/ci/';

Comment: Thanks! submit as answer i'll mark it...

Comment: @GeertJaminon it can't be debugged using `site_url();`, it can be debugged with `base_url();`

Comment: @Vlakarados `site_url();` returns the same thing for me as `base_url();` does, then again, in this case it did help solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your config for base_url and site_url

Leave them '' blank.